# Cumulative BitWise OR on Char Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, bitwise-operators

I have a long char array size of 7K.

```
char arr[] = "1110010011....." ; // length 7K
```

I have to perform cumulative OR on array with window size of let say 3.
That means:

```
arr[0] | arr[1] | arr[2] ;

arr[1] | arr[2] | arr[3] ;
```

what can be the best way can I do it less than `O(n)` or even if complexity is `O(n)` how can we make it faster?

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: based on your example, you need to go through all "n" elements. O(n) will be the complexity

Comment: C++ @Nandu , Why -1 I don't understand what problem you found.. and at the same time when I am saying even if complexity is O(n) how can we do faster ..

Comment: BTW, i did not down vote. If the complexity is O(n) and you agree, then what do you mean by doing faster? are u looking for O(logn)??

Comment: I would expect significant speed-ups to come from re-using operation results. There is a commonly used technique for "running sums", invertible operations like numeric `+` - bit-wise or is not invertible. _If_ you have an additional array of about the same size (e.g., to hold the results), can you gain anything from doing pair-wise _or_ s first? (In real life, saving operations like this might even impair performance - this might be the occasion to learn to avoid the easiest fallacies in benchmarking.)

Comment: There is another angle to this: how many consecutive `1`s do you need for a `1` result, and how many consecutive `0`s for a `0`? (You are welcome to answer your own question here - there even is a badge for it.)

Answer (score 3):

If you repack your zero-one array into a bitset, then you can do it significantly faster. It would be about 32 times faster, but still take *O(N)* time. Also, you can use 64-bit words on 64-bit machine, then you'll get 64x improvement.

Note however, that for large *N* memory bandwidth would become the main bottleneck, so only 8x improvement would be achieved (because size is reduced in 8 times).

Here is the sample code:

```
int main() {
    char arr[] = "01000001011111000110010000011000111";
    int n = strlen(arr);

    //preparation: convert to bitset
    uint32_t bitset[sizeof(arr) / 32 + 3] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      bitset[i/32] ^= (arr[i]=='1') << (i % 32);
    //solution: bit operations
    uint32_t result[sizeof(bitset) / sizeof(bitset[0])] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < (n + 31) / 32; i++) {
        uint32_t curr = bitset[i], next = bitset[i+1];
        result[i] = curr | (curr >> 1) | (next << 31) | (curr >> 2) | (next << 30);
    }

    printf("%s\n ", arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < n+2; i++)
        printf("%d", (result[i/32] >> (i%32)) & 1);
}
```

### Update

The approach described above takes *O(N W)* time for variable window width *W*. For small *W* it is the fastest one, but it is not very efficient for large *W*.

Note that the problem can be solved in *O(N)* time for any window size. For example, you can precalculate [prefix sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) for your array of zeros/ones in *O(N)* time. Then for each window it is possible to determine the number of ones inside it in *O(1)* time as a difference of two sum values. As a result, you get a simple *O(N)* solution. It does not use any bitsets, and it is the fastest approach for really large *W*.

For intermediate window sizes (like *W = 16*), it is possible to modify the bitset-based approach to work in *O(N log W)* time, which may be faster than *O(N W)* version. The approach is somewhat similar to parallel reduction. Here is the sample code for *W = 13*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n + 31) / 32; i++) {
    uint64_t curr = *(uint64_t*)&bitset[i];
    curr |= (curr >> 1);
    curr |= (curr >> 2);
    curr |= (curr >> 4);
    curr |= (curr >> 5);
    result[i] = uint32_t(curr);
}
```

Comment: I'd think you could get `result` even faster converting everything to `uint64_t` array (or `uint128_t` if possible) and doing a bitwise-`&` on `curr` with a bitmask that shifts and a `> 0` comparision since the example is just doing a bitwise-or on single bits - if any one is non-zero, the result is 1, else the result is 0.  You'd need to handle the transition to `next` but the rollover to `next` shouldn't impact performance much.  That would  eliminate 3 shift operations in your loop, and the first loop entirely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I assume that it is possible to store the array of bits in a bitset from the very beginning. So the first loop is only for illustration, and it does not matter how slow it is.

I do not understand you suggestion. If it is really different, perhaps you should post it as another answer.

Comment: That is great just eager to know what if my window size also vary, in spite of three can vary from 3 to 100

Comment: @KumarVishal: I have updated solution with two more approaches. You can check yourself which of them is faster for which size.

Comment: @stgatilov for you solution

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of size N, which contains only 0's and 1's, and you want the result of ORing each K items (where K is the window size), all you have to do is keep track of where the last '1' is.

```
int last1 = -1;
int range_start = 0;
int range_end = window_size - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    if (a[i] == '1')
    {
        last1 = i;
    }
    if (i == range_end)
    {
        if (last1 >= range_start)
            // output 1
        else
            // output 0
    }
    ++range_start;
    ++range_end;
}
```

The idea here is that cumulative OR for any window size will be 1 if there is one or more 1's in the window. If the window contains all 0's, then the result is 0.

You might be able to optimize that a little bit by looking at the first `window_size - 1` values in a separate loop, thereby eliminating the `range_end` variable, but it complicates your loop a little bit. I don't know if it'd be a net win.

Answer (score -3):

To clarify, you'd like your output array to have n elements in it, each of which has the value of arr[n-1] | arr[n] | arr[n+1]. (with the possible exception of the first and the last elements, which don't have an arr[n-1] and arr[n+1] respectively.

If that's correct, then it is not possible to do this in less than O(n). You need to look at every element in the array at least once which alone takes O(n) time.

Fortunately, even the most naive approach meets that O(n) goal:

```
int size = strlen(arr);
char arr2[size];
for (int i=1; i<size-1; i++) { //ignore first and last element
    if (arr[i-1] == '1' || arr[i] == '1' || arr[i+2] == '1') {
        arr2[i] = '1';
    } else {
        arr2[i] = '0';
    }
}
```

At that point you have to decide what you mean by "efficient". You need to decide whether you want to reduce comparisons or assignments. Depending on your situation, either of these could be a valid choice and would result in very different solutions.

Comment: I am not very bothered about space it is ok for me. I can store it in altogether different array.

Comment: OP wants faster algorithm. Not one that saves space